# A (analytical) Geometric Way to solve this complex number problem?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> **Problem** Let $a_0,a_1,a_2$ be three complex numbers that lie on the circle $C$ with center $K(2,0)$ and radius $r=1$. Let $v \in \mathbb
>  C$ such that
>
> $$v^3 + a_2v^2 + a_1v + a_0 = 0$$
>
> Prove that $|v|<4$

There is a way to solve this by a lot of algebra and inequality usage (trig inequalities etc.) which is this:

Boring method:
\begin{eqnarray}
|v^3| &=& |a_2v^2 + a_1v + a_0| \\
&\leq & |a_2||v|^2 + |a_1||v| + |a_0| \\
&\leq & 3|v|^2 + 3|v| + 3
\end{eqnarray}

Which implies $|v|^3 - 3|v|^2 - 3|v| - 3 \leq 0$.

Let $f:\mathbb R^*_+ \to \mathbb R: f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 - 3x -3$ with derivative $f'(x) = 3(x^2 - 2x - 1)$.
Suppose that $|v| \geq 4$ so $f(|v|) \geq 1$ ($f$ is increasing)which is not true so $|v|<4$

So, I was wondering (as a matter of personal research) if there was a "more clever"/creative, namely a geometric way, to solve it.What if the points $M_1(v^3)$, $M_2(a_2v^2)$, $M_3(a_1v)$, $M_4(a_0)$ define a quadrilateral $M_1M_2M_3M_4$ and then use geometry to solve the problem but I don't have any "creative" ideas on it. Is there one?

Comment: Maybe there's a Rouche's theorem connection to be had here.

Comment: Hmm, could you please explain your thought?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I'm pretty drained today but maybe someone else can fill in the ideas.

Comment: I worked out the Rouche theorem approach. It's not hard to check it, even if you don't know complex analysis, but the proof is pretty complex analysis intensive. It's not a geometric proof per se, but it's a nice way to see it. Rouche's theorem says that if you have two (holomorphic) functions $f$ and $g$ that satisfy $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$ on some contour (think a closed path in the plane like a circle), then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of roots inside the contour.

Comment: If we pick $f(z) = z^3$ and $g(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2 z^2$ for our functions and our contour to be the circle of radius $4$ centered at the origin, then we have that $|f(z)| = 64$ and $$|g(z)| \le |a_0| + |a_1||z| + |a_2||z|^2 \le 3+3\cdot 4 + 3\cdot 4^2 = 63.$$ Since $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on the circle, it follows that $a_0 + a_1z + a_2 z^2 + z^3$ and $z^3$ have the same number of roots inside the circle of radius $4$. $z^3$ has a triple root at zero and so $a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + z^3$ has all of its roots inside the circle of radius $4$ as desired.

Comment: This isn't *exactly* a geometric proof but Rouche's theorem is a very geometric theorem so it sort of counts?

Comment: As a hobbyist, I know things about complex analysis (however I'm in high school). By the way, thanks!